# Trying to print only radio button’s data from cookie in which selected data stored But it’s printing both checkbox and radio button’s stored data

Tags: php, cookies, checkbox, radio-button, cart

We have checkboxes and radio button in our product page as data ,
we are store selected data in cookie and when user click on continue button page will redirect to cart page , on cart page we are printing selected stored data in card but when we only want radio button’s stored selected data to be print but using my code it’s printing both checkbox and radio button’s selected data.

here is full code of our cart page ,

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <?php include('plugins.php'); ?>
    
        <!-- Include your stylesheets and scripts here -->
        <style>
            .card {
                background-color: white;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                border: 0px;
                border-radius: 30px;
                padding: 20px;
                padding-left: 0px;
                box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -7px #c9dff0;
                margin: 20px;
                text-align: left; /* Align cards to the left */
                font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
                font-size: 1rem;
                font-weight: 500;
                line-height: 1.3;
                position: relative;
            }
    
            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: space-between; /* Align cards and order summary */
                align-items: flex-start; /* Align cards to the left */
            }
    
            .col-md-7 {
                flex: 0 0 auto; /* Prevent cards from growing to fill the space */
            }
    
            .order-summary {
                flex: 0 0 auto; /* Prevent order summary from growing to fill the space */
                padding-top: 100px; /* Add top padding */
            }
    
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'header.php'; include('toast.php'); include 'wpBtn.php'; ?>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="col-md-7">
                
    
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <?php
                    // Check if the selected data cookie exists
                    if (isset($_COOKIE['selectedData'])) {
                        // Retrieve the selected data from the cookie
                        $selectedData = json_decode($_COOKIE['selectedData'], true);
    
                        // Display the selected data
                        echo "<h2></h2>";
    
                        // Flag to track if the "Remove" line card has been printed
                        $removeLinePrinted = false;
    
                        // Counter for the selected checkboxes
                        $selectedCount = 0;
    
                        // Loop through the selected data and display each item in a card format
                        foreach ($selectedData as $sub_name => $data) {
                            // Print the "Remove" line card only once at the top
                            if (!$removeLinePrinted) {
                                echo "<div class='card' style='border-bottom: none;'>";
                                echo "<div class='card-body d-flex justify-content-between'>";
                                echo "    <div class='form-check'>";
                                echo "        <input class='form-check-input' style='margin-top: .35rem;' type='checkbox' value='' id='allPurchaseCheck'>";
                                echo "        <label class='form-check-label' style='font-size: .77rem;font-family: 'Varela Round', serif;font-weight:bold;'><b style='font-size: .88rem;'><span id='total_selected_item'>$selectedCount</span>/<span id='total_items'></span> ITEMS SELECTED</b></label>";
                                echo "    </div>";
                                echo "    <div id='remove-all-item' style='cursor: pointer;font-family: 'Varela Round', serif;font-weight:bold;'>REMOVE</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
    
                                $removeLinePrinted = true;
                            }
    
                            // Open the card div for the current item
                            echo "<div class='card' style='border-bottom: none;'>";
    
                            // Print the rest of the card content for the current item
    
                            echo "<div class='card-body d-flex justify-content-between position-relative'>";
                            echo "    <input class='form-check-input position-absolute purch-checkbox' style='margin-top: .2rem;' type='checkbox' id='purch'>";
                            echo "    <div style='background-color: #B3B2B1; height: 9rem; padding: 6% 15% 10%; width: 8rem;' class='float-start'>";
                            echo "        <?php ?>";
                            echo "    </div>";
                            echo "<div class='float-start ms-3'>";
                            echo "<h5> " . str_replace('_', ' ', $sub_name) . " </h5>";
    
                            // Check if the $data variable is an array
                            if (is_array($data)) {
                                foreach ($data as $material_name => $attempts) {
                                    echo "<h5> " . str_replace('_', ' ', $material_name) . "</h5>";
    
                                    // Check if the $attempts variable is an array
                                    if (is_array($attempts)) {
                                        // Find the radio button selection
                                        $radioSelection = null;
                                        foreach ($attempts as $attempt_name => $price) {
                                            if (strpos($attempt_name, 'radio_') !== false) {
                                                $radioSelection = $attempt_name;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
    
                                        // Display the radio button selection, if found
                                        if ($radioSelection !== null) {
                                            $price = str_replace('_', ' ', $attempts[$radioSelection]);
                                            $firstPart = substr($price, 0, 3);
                                            $secondPart = substr($price, 3);
                                            echo "<p class='price'>Selected Attempt Name: " . str_replace('_', ' ', $radioSelection) . "</p>";
                                            echo "<p class='price'>Selected Attempt Price: <span>$firstPart</span><br><span>$secondPart</span></p>";
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        // If $attempts is not an array, assume it's the price and display it
                                        $price = str_replace('_', ' ', $attempts);
                                        $firstPart = substr($price, 0, 3);
                                        $secondPart = substr($price, 3, -5);
                                        echo "<h5 class='price'><p>" . $secondPart . "<span style='float: right;'>₹ " . $firstPart . "</span></p></h5>";
                                                
                                        //echo "<h5 class='price'> <span style='text-align: right;'>₹ $firstPart</span><br><span>$secondPart</span></h5>";
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                // If $data is not an array, assume it's the price and display it
                                $price = str_replace('_', ' ', $data);
                                $firstPart = substr($price, 0, 3);
                                $secondPart = substr($price, 3);
                                echo "<p class='price' style='text-align: right;'><span>₹ $firstPart</span></p>"; // Display $firstPart on the right side
                                echo "<p class='price'> <span>₹ $firstPart</span><br><span>$secondPart</span></p>";
                                    }
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "    <i class='bi bi-x-lg position-absolute top-0 end-0 mt-1' style='margin-right:.55rem;font-size:.85rem;cursor:pointer;' id='remove_card' data-id='<?php echo $v; ?>'></i>";
                            echo "</div>";
    
                            // Close the card div for the current item
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
    
                    } else {
                        echo "<p>No data selected.</p>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
    
            <div class="order-summary">
                <div style="border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;padding: 1rem 1rem;background-color: #FFF;">
                    <div style="font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;">
                        <h3 style="font-weight:200;">Order Summary</h3>
                        <span style="display:none;float: right;"><b>₹ <span id="total_price"></span></b></span>
                        <hr style="background-color: #babfbb;">
                        <h6 style="text-align: left;">
                            <div class="form-check" style="font-size:1.05rem;display:inline-block;">
                                <label class="form-check-label h-100 align-middle" for="physical_notes">Printable PDFs &nbsp;</label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <b>₹ <span style="float: right;"><span id="total_price2"></span></span></b> -->
                            <span style="float: right;"> <b>₹ <span id="total_price2"><?php echo $_COOKIE['total_price']; ?></span></b></span>
                        </h6>
                        <div class=" d-md-block">
                            <hr style="background-color: #babfbb;">
                                <!-- <h6 style="text-align: left;">
                                    <div class="form-check" style="font-size:1.05rem;display:inline-block;">
                                        <label class="form-check-label h-100 align-middle" for="physical_notes">Total Price &nbsp;</label>
                                    </div>
                                     <b>₹ <span style="float: right;"><span id="total_price2"></span></span></b> 
                                    <span style="float: right;"> <b>₹ <span id="total_price2"><//?php echo $_COOKIE['total_price']; ?></span></b></span>
                                </h6> -->
    
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: #f05969;color: #fff;width:100%;border-color:#f05969;" id="continue">CONTINUE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Include your scripts here -->
        <script>
            // Get all the purchase checkboxes
            const purchCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.purch-checkbox');
    
            // Get the total_selected_item element
            const totalSelectedElement = document.getElementById('total_selected_item');
    
            // Update the selected count when a checkbox is checked or unchecked
            function updateSelectedCount() {
                const selectedCount = Array.from(purchCheckboxes).filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked).length;
                totalSelectedElement.textContent = selectedCount;
            }
    
            // Add event listeners to the checkboxes
            purchCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
                checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateSelectedCount);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.